# Cannot Bind Complex type in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having the below PaymentInformationModel Class. Which is having a complex type CreditCardDetailModel. When I submit my form the CreditCartDetail property remain empty, I am expecting it to be filled with all the details entered by the user. Do I need to do custom binding or there is a default binding trick which I am missing.

**PaymentInformationModel**

```
 public class PaymentInformationModel
{

    public string PaymentAmount { get; set; }


    public string TransactionReference { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CreditCardDetailModel CreditCardDetail{get;set;}

}
```

**CreditCardDetailModel**

```
public class CreditCardDetailModel
    {


        public string CardNumber { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }


        public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }



        public int CardSecurityCode { get; set; }

        public CreditCardType CardType { get; set; }


    }
```

**VIEW**

```
    @model PaymentInformationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Payment", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "Form1", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Payment Information</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PaymentAmount, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
                    <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentAmount, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-10" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PaymentAmount, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TransactionReference, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.TransactionReference, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-10" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(l => l.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(t => t.Description, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-10"  })
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
       @Html.Action("CreditCardDetail")
        <p class="log"></p>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success">PAY</button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(PaymentInformationModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }
            return View();
        }



 public PartialViewResult CreditCardDetail()
        {
            return PartialView("CreditCardDetail_Partial");
        }
```

Comment: Your `CreditCardDetail` property has a getter only. The `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** it. Change the property to `public CreditCardDetailModel CreditCardDetail { get; set; }`

Comment: Why does your `CreditCardDetailModel` have a property for another `CreditCardDetailModel`?

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: What does `@Html.Action("CreditCardDetail")` return? (show the relevant code) - Unless its generating the correctly prefixed `name` attributes, then it will not bind

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: @maxspan, Does it generate form controls with `name="CreditCardDetail.CardNumber"`, `name="CreditCardDetail.ExpiryDate"` etc. And why are you using `@Html.Action()` for this. The correct approach is to use an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `CreditCardDetailModel`

Comment: No its having name= 'CardNumber' without the CreditCardDetail.

Comment: Hmm. Let me try your approach using EditorTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `@Html.Action()` is calling a controller method that returns a partial view of `CreditCardDetailModel` which will generate inputs with name attributes such as

```
<input name="CardNumber" .... />
<input name="ExpiryDate" .... />
```

but in order to bind to your model, they need to be

```
<input name="CreditCardDetail.CardNumber" .... />
<input name="CreditCardDetail.ExpiryDate" .... />
```

Its unclear why your using `@Html.Action()` to call a server method that contains no logic, and you could just have easily use `@Html.Partial("CreditCardDetail_Partial")`, although that will still result in the same incorrect `name` attribute.

You need to use an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `CreditCardDetailModel`. Move your `CreditCardDetail_Partial.cshtml` file to the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder and rename it to `CreditCardDetailModel.cshtml` (i.e. to match the name of the class). Then in the view, use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CreditCardDetail)
```

which will generate the correct `name` attributes for binding to your model.

Comment: Actually I already created a ParitalView for CreditCardDetail model. And so I  binded my parital view with its parent model i.e PaymentInformationModel which have CreditCardDetailModel property and I binded all my controls like this.  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreditCardDetail.CardNumber, new { @class="form-control", placeholder= "Card Number" }). Also I wanted a customised look and feel for my view so I didnot used EditorFor, But definitely its a good option.

Comment: Using `EditorFor()` has nothing to do with _a customised look and feel for my view_ (you can style it however you want)

Comment: so I can I used my Partialview in EditorFor.

Comment: Yes. Just rename it and move it to the `EditorTemplates` folder as per my answer.